# 2-D ICP for PCL

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

The ICP module in PCL is used specifically for 3-dimensional point clouds, i.e. there can be 3D transformations. Is there a way to implement 2D ICP in PCL, i.e. the z is fixed and transformations must be 2D?

Answer (score 0):

Under [registration module](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.8.1/group__registration.html), you can find `pcl::registration::TransformationEstimation2D<...>`. This class expects the two input point clouds to be aligned vertically and also the correspondences estimated *a priori* as explained [here](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.8.1/classpcl_1_1registration_1_1_transformation_estimation2_d.html).

Comment: So there isn't a packed interface for `icp2d`? What we can do is just implement it using `TransformationEstimation2D` and `CorrespondenceEstimation`?

Comment: The links in this answer no longer work.